# How to deploy Preview slot for FoxIDs app?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, foxids

I would like to deploy preview/test slot for [FoxIDs](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/FoxIDs) solution. No problem to deploy update on (test slot) and swap it with production one with or without auto swap settings.
But I can't start test slot as preview to check it before swap it with production.
`HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start` error is shown.
There is nothing interesting in App and IIS Logs also.

How to create preview slot for [FoxIDs](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/FoxIDs) solution and run it in parallel with production slot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need grant the two App Service test slots access to production keys (certificates) and add test slot configuration in FoxIDs Control, if you want to use production data in the test slots.

The two App Service test slots (FoxIDs site and FoxIDs Control site) is granted access to the Key vault in Key vault --> Access policies. Marked with green arrows.

[image]

Before you can run FoxIDs Control in the test slot, you need to open FoxIDs Control with the master tenants down-parties in the main/production site https://foxidscontrolxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/master/downparties (or use your custom domain). Then select `foxids_control_client`, click show advanced settings and add the test slots CORS origins and login and logout redirect URLs.

[image]